# How to convert a list of strings to a dict of lists where keys start with given substring

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
list = ['ID - ISO', 'CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2', 'ID - ISO6', 'CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2', 'CATA - CIT6', 'CATA - CIT8']
```

I would like to create a dictionary like this

```
dict = {'ID - ISO': ['CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2'], 
        'ID - ISO6': ['CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2', 'CATA - CIT6', 'CATA - CIT8']}
```

So I developed this code but when I add the values, it is not working: the values are the same for all the ids.

```
with open("/data/myfile") as openfile:
        for line in openfile:
        for single_line in line.split('\\'):
            if line.startswith("ID"):
                 Dict[line] = None
            elif line.startswith("CATA"):
                for li in Dict:
                    Dict[li]=line
print Dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = ['ID - ISO', 'CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2','ID - ISO6', 'CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2', 'CATA - CIT6', 'CATA - CIT8']

result = {}
for k,v in groupby(lst, lambda x: x.startswith('ID')):
    if k:
        key = next(v)
    else:
        result[key] = list(v)

print(result)
```

Which would yield

```
{
 'ID - ISO': ['CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2'], 
 'ID - ISO6': ['CATA - CIT', 'CATA - CIT2', 'CATA - CIT6', 'CATA - CIT8']
}
```

Additionally, do not call your variables after builtin types (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`, etc.) - you're effectively shadowing the functionality if you do.